# Android LinearLayout content not displayed

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using LinearyLayout as you see and my problem is why cant i see the imageview at the firstline and the button at the secondline?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageview"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal">
           <Button
               android:id="@+id/button"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest an improvement to the title, such as "LinearLayout content not displayed".

Comment: Why on Earth do you enclose each View in a ViewGroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button has no text and the imageview no image to display? Unless you are setting that in code.
As both those are set to have a height (`wrap_content`) matching their content, they will have a height of 0 (not showing).

You can set `android:layout_height` to have a fixed height (`40dp` for example) instead or provide the data.

Adding:

```
android:text="My button"
```

to the button displays the button for example.

Adding:

```
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
```

to the image view shows the image.

Comment: "You can set android:layout_height to have a fixed height (40dp for example) instead or provide the data."                                                                     This is the problem.Thank you !

Comment: I would not suggest the fixed height option though, instead set the text and image. Feel free to both upvote AND accept the answer ;-)

Comment: I accepted it :) And by the way, making the fixed height can make a problem in different size of screens?

Comment: Well first of all the content (text or image) might not fit!

Comment: Let's assume that it fit,so can it be a problem in different scren sizes?

Comment: Possibly depending on your height and the devices text sizes, fonts used (by you or the devices default ones etc). Also note that text size can be changed by the user for easier reading. I really suggest keeping wrap_content but at some point provide the text etc to the button.